# What is += in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

For example, in the while loop:

```
while (i < 10) {
    text += "The number is " + i;
    i++;
}
```

What does it do? Thanks.

Comment: [+=](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is the **[`addition assignment`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)** operator (`+=`) to add a value to a variable.

Depending of the current type of the defined value on a variable, it will read the current value add/concat another value into it and define on the same variable.

For a `string`, you concat the current value with another value

```
let name = "User";

name += "Name"; // name = "UserName";
name += " is ok"; // name = "UserName is ok";
```

It is the same:

```
var name = "User";

name = name + "Name"; // name = "UserName";
name = name + " is ok"; // name = "UserName is ok";
```

For numbers, it will sum the value:

```
let n = 3;

n += 2; // n = 5
n += 3; // n = 8
```

In Javascript, we also have the following expressions:

- `-=` - Subtraction assignment;
- `/=` - Division assignment;
- `*=` - Multiplication assignment;
- `%=` - Modulus (Division Remainder) assignment.

Answer (score 6):

```
text += "The number is " + i;
```

is equivalent to

```
text = text + "The number is " + i;
```